# How to add three months from incoming API dates using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, postman

How do you calculate dates from the database by adding 3 months?

I created a LINQ query that only selects the column EndYearMonth from the database. I was trying to set up a variable in the parameters called EndYearMonth which is also placed in the DateTime object. I got the DateTime function code using this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/datetime-addmonths-method-in-chash. The problem is that this tutorial doesn't show you how to add three months from the database because there is only one date that is hardcoded.

Here is my code below

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetFinance(int EndYearMonth )
        {
            var dates = _context.Finances

                .Select(e => e.EndYearMonth
                )  
                
                .ToList();

            

        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(EndYearMonth);
         DateTime Q1 = d1.AddMonths(3);
         DateTime Q2 = d1.AddMonths(6);
         DateTime Q3 = d1.AddMonths(9);
   
        
        DateTime[] array = {Q1, Q2 , Q3};

        return Ok(array);
         
        



        }
```

> When I click send to get the request the output is this

[image]

The expected outcome should be this

[image]

This is the original data coming from the database

[image]

Comment: The DateTime is instantiated with 0 in your case.
Therefore `GetFinance` is somehow called with 0 as the given argument.

Comment: The code is right the EndOfYearDate is wrong that is why you get wrong dates

Comment: The [DateTime ctor with a single value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int64_) does NOT set the year, but the number of "ticks" since the start of year 0001 - that's why you get strange results. Use `new DateTime(year, 1, 1)` to get Jan 1st of that year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetFinance()
{
    var dates = _context.Finances
                    .Select(e => e.EndYearMonth)
                    .ToList();

    int arrayLength = dates.Count() * 4;
    DateTime[] array = new DateTime[arrayLength];
    int index = 0;
    
    foreach (var strDate in dates)
    {
        DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse(strDate);
        DateTime Q1 = d1.AddMonths(3);
        DateTime Q2 = d1.AddMonths(6);
        DateTime Q3 = d1.AddMonths(9);
        array[index] = d1;
        array[index + 1] = Q1;
        array[index + 2] = Q2;
        array[index + 3] = Q3;
        index += 4;
    }

    return Ok(array);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get EndOfYearDate from database as it is and then add 3 months to it. The code of adding 3 months is right but the line code below is wrong

```
 DateTime d1 = new DateTime(EndYearMonth);
```

To resolve this simply get the datetime from database as it is and then add 3 months to it.